# VB.net Textbox, how to get Newline Symbol (little arrow, same as in enter key)

Tags: vb.net, return, symbols, linefeed

In Visual Basic.net I managed to get this little arrow symbol `↵`  in the TextBox some time ago, but lost it.

Is this font dependent? I used Consolas and Courier New.
Do i need a RichTextBox or something else?

I tried `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`, `environment.newline` and `vbLf`, `vbCr` and what else but I'm lost.

I just want to have that special character to be visible for "debug purposes".
My system is UTF capable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextBox` does not display unprintable characters, like most text editors can do.

You can, however, simply insert the `↵` symbol yourself, be replacing each newline character with `↵` and a newline character.

**Example:**

```
Dim f = New Form()
Dim txt = New TextBox() With { .MultiLine = True, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}

Dim text = <text>This is just
                 some multine text
                 to be displayed</text>.Value

txt.Text = Regex.Replace(text, "(\n\r|\r|\n)", "↵$1")

f.Controls.Add(txt)
f.ShowDialog()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will do the trick! Somehow I managed to do this in some other way also but how, that remains as a mystery. (Like I mentioned I forgot the code allready)

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard character, no fancy fonts required.

Here's all you could wish to know about it..

**Encodings**

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8629;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x21b5;
HTML Entity (named) &crarr;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +21B5
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x86 0xB5 (e286b5)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000110:10110101
UTF-16 (hex)    0x21B5 (21b5)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8,629
UTF-32 (hex)    0x000021B5 (21b5)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8,629
C/C++/Java source code  "\u21B5"
Python source code  u"\u21B5"
```

Comment: My textbox is readonly and I write to it in my code. I write CR/LF to end of every line. But I can't see that symbol in the text box. I know this should be possible somehow. But normally it doesn't appear there, of course.